# Rails 3.2.1 redirect_to not rendering page when using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Apologies if this is a really silly question or I've done something really stupid, I'm still a newbie.
I'm trying to implement a session timeout mechanism, and I've found some useful questions/answers in SO for this, which I've followed. I've added a last_seen time as a session variable and I'm checking this in a before_filter in my application controller, which if more than a set interval, sends the user back to the logon page.

Application Controller

```
reset_session if session[:last_seen] < 1.minutes.ago

if session[:user_id] == nil
  redirect_to login_path, notice: "Please log in"
  return
end

session[:last_seen] = Time.now
```

This works fine on most pages, but I have some pages that are tabbed, using jquery to change the contents using partials as tabs are selected.

Link code:

```
<li class="<%=get_active('index_audit','ultra')%>"><%= link_to 'Load  IT Estate', ultraaudit_path, remote: true %> </li>
```

Controller Code:

```
def index_audit

  @subscription = current_subscription

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end

end
```

There's an index_audt.js that has the JS to replace a div with a rendered partial

If the time out occurs and the next action is click a tab to render the next page, its goes through the code but doesn't display the login page in the browser

I'm debugging in RubyMine and the console shows its trying to render the login page, which is sessions/new:

```
Processing by UltraController#index_audit as JS
Parameters: {"locale"=>"en-GB"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/?locale=en-GB
Filter chain halted as :logged_in rendered or redirected    
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/?locale=en-GB" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-14 11:28:44 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#new as JS
Parameters: {"locale"=>"en-GB"}
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 323ms (Views: 320.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But it just doesn't appear in the browser

I've tried putting a redirect at the top of the index_audit controller method  and that has the same problem.
My theory is that the remote: true is the cause, but I don't know what to do to fix it. Can any-one out there help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user's session is still valid, the `index_audit` action will return JS, but if the user's session expired, it will return the HTML for the login page.  Presumably, your remote handler is expecting JS format, so it doesn't see anything it can do with the HTML response containing the login page.

The best approach would probably be to add a `format.js` option to `SessionsController.new`, and create the necessary `new.js.erb` view, so that if you request javascript format, you always get javascript whether the session is expired or not.

Comment: Thanks, Charles, that's a brilliant idea - I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who had this issue (as i did after upgrading rails 3.0 to 3.1), where the proposed fix did not work or was different than your own.

Removing `:remote => true` from the form_for tag allowed the submit and redirect to go through. Which makes sense since the last form wasn't using ajax to get a response.

Hope this helps someone else!